# Intellij can’t import dependency import by spring-boot-starter

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, snakeyaml

I want use `org.yaml.snake.Yaml` in my springboot application. Since the spring-boot-starter has already included the snakeYML. thus I don't need import the `org.yaml.snake.Yaml` again in my pom.xml file.

when I type  `import org.yaml.snake.Yaml` in source code, **eclipse** can exactly import it. However, when I use the Intellij it can't import the package.
As I edit the pom.xml and add below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

It works fine!

I wander is this a bug of intellij?

Comment: dont think so. did you reimport the pom in intellij? If my memory is not wrong there is an action in the context menu of the pom.xml like reimport. This must be done when changing the pom.xml. Intellij also asks you if you want to enable autoreimport after the first change of the pom.xml. (This is just valid if you added the starter after first import, otherwise maybe a bug) Which starter did you import?

Comment: In case of a [Maven project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html) IntelliJ IDEA automatically configures dependencies, based on Maven pom.xml file so you would get the exact same behavior if you would build/run the project by Maven from command line.